# Limiting Oracle instances resources with Cgroups?

Tags: performance, oracle, cgroup

Is it possible to limit the amount of resources (I/O, CPU and Memory) a Oracle instance can consume using only cgroups? (no containers or virtualization)

The reason I wanna do that is because I want to run performance tests repeatedly on two different oracle instances, at the same time, that are located on the same physical server, and I want to keep the results as consistent as possible.

If it is possible, is that the best way to it?

Thanks.